# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException in Apache Storm after migration to 1.0.0

Tags: java, maven, apache-storm, classnotfoundexception

I tried to migrate my simple *Trident DRPC topology* to `Apache Storm` 1.0.0 (from 0.10.0) and test it in a local in-memory mode. It's really simple topology with 1 bolt, so migration required only to replace `backtype.storm` and `storm.trident` to `org.apache.storm` and `org.apache.storm.trident`.

Unfortunately, I start getting errors like (with possible different missing classes for different topologies):

```sh
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.trident.partition.IdentityGrouping
```

It's too weird to report issues on my specific topology, so I reproduced the issue with the `storm-starter` topology. Since, I'm interesting in testing on *in-memory cluster* I've chosen the [ExclamationTopology](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/v1.0.0/examples/storm-starter/src/jvm/org/apache/storm/starter/ExclamationTopology.java).

```sh
> cd storm/examples/storm-starter
> mvn clean install -DskipTests=true
> mvn exec:java -Dstorm.topology=storm.starter.ExclamationTopology -DskipTests=true
```

The commands above started the local cluster, but after topology was submitted it also ended with a `RuntimeException`:

```sh
8632 [Thread-11] ERROR o.a.s.d.worker - Error on initialization of server mk-worker
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.testing.TestWordSpout
  at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.javaDeserialize(Utils.java:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.utils.Utils.getSetComponentObject(Utils.java:430) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$get_task_object.invoke(task.clj:74) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data$fn__7593.invoke(task.clj:177) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.util$assoc_apply_self.invoke(util.clj:930) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task_data.invoke(task.clj:170) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.daemon.task$mk_task.invoke(task.clj:181) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at org.apache.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor$fn__7812.invoke(executor.clj:371) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
  at clojure.core$map$fn__4553.invoke(core.clj:2622) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]
  at clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval(LazySeq.java:40) ~[clojure-1.7.0.jar:?]

....

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.storm.testing.TestWordSpout
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348) ~[?:1.8.0_77]
  at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.commons.io.input.ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.resolveClass(ClassLoaderObjectInputStream.java:68) ~[storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]

....
```

There are few similar issues already reported for older versions, but there was no clear solution or issue was too generic.

Of course, I've also checked the dependency tree and `storm-core` is included, so I think it's somehow related to serialization issues and the way I execute the topology in a local mode.

**Any suggestions?** I use `Apache Maven` 3.3.9 and `Java` 1.8.0_77 on `Ubuntu` 14.04. Here is my [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/xsVXEgGK)

Comment: A lot of packages got renamed in the new release. It sounds like a jar version mismatch... make sure to get rid of all old jar files and only use 1.0 stuff. If the problem does not go away, you might have hit a bug... If so, please report to dev@storm.apache.org

Comment: It's only 2 files in my topology and I tried it on a completely fresh machine, so unlikely I forgot to remove any jars ... weird. If don't get idea soon, will report to dev list.

Comment: were you able to figure out what the issue was?

Comment: unfortunately, I wrote to dev@storm, but no reactions so far. So, I fell back to 0.10.0